# Linux Mint на флэшке

Tags: linux-mint

Linux переносной(на флешке), очень долго загружается при нажатии F11,чтобы выбрать откуда загружаться.
Так и должно быть? Наверное,в "задний" порт компьютера надо флешку вставлять? Или вообще взять переносной жёсткий диск более скоростной?
Потом перед загрузкой выскакивает:

```
    [ 10.712047] ata2.00:SRST failed (errno=-16)
    [ 20.772049] ata2.00:SRST failed (errno=-16)
    [ 55.816055] ata2.00:SRST failed (errno=-16)
```

Наконец-загружается и всё работает,
Но, всё таки ,что это? Чего то не хватает?
[image: скрин перед запуском]

---

Устанавливал из Windows7,с помощью VirtualBox,предварительно скачав образ Linux
"очень долго"...минуты 3-4,основная операционная система с жёсткого диска-почти сразу.

Comment: А как устанавливали на флешку?

Comment: "очень долго" это сколько?